# How to get objects in JsonModel output RESTful API

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

**This code is working fine:**

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{ 
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(
            array(
                  'albums' => $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album')->findAll() 
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**This code sent empty objects:**

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function getList()
    {
        return new JsonModel(
            array(
                'albums' => $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album')->findAll() 
            )
        );
    }
}

//is returning result like this
{"albums":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never get valid json output if you just embed your `Album` objects in an array like that...
The `JsonModel` class will not be able to convert/serialize them to valid json data that is why you get `{}` (an empty object) for each `Album`.

Either implement a `JsonSerializable` interface including the needed code in a `jsonSerialize` method your `Album` class or convert to something that `JsonModel` knows how to serialize like an array in your controller method.

With `JsonSerializable`:

```
class Album implements JsonSerializable {
    // ...

    function jsonSerialize() {
        //some means of serializing the data...
    }
}
```

---

Or simply do it manually inside the `AlbumController` in your `getList` method:

```
$albums = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Album\Entity\Album')->findAll()

$array = [];

foreach( $albums as $album ){       
    $array[] = [
        'id' => $album->getId(),
        'name' => $album->getName()
    ]
}

return new JsonModel(
    array(
        'albums' => $array
    );
);
```